# Animating a 2D plot (2D brownian motion) not working in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, ffmpeg, visualization, stochastic-process

I am trying to plot a 2D Brownian motion in Python but my plot plots the grid but does not animate the line.

Attempted at performing this plot is below,

```
!apt install ffmpeg

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


np.random.seed(5)


# Set up formatting for the movie files
Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=15, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)


def generateRandomLines(dt, N):
    dX = np.sqrt(dt) * np.random.randn(1, N)
    X = np.cumsum(dX, axis=1)

    dY = np.sqrt(dt) * np.random.randn(1, N)
    Y = np.cumsum(dY, axis=1)

    lineData = np.vstack((X, Y))

    return lineData


# Returns Line2D objects
def updateLines(num, dataLines, lines):
    for u, v in zip(lines, dataLines):
        u.set_data(v[0:2, :num])

    return lines

N = 501 # Number of points
T = 1.0
dt = T/(N-1)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data = [generateRandomLines(dt, N)]

ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-2.0, 2.0), ylim=(-2.0, 2.0))

ax.set_xlabel('X(t)')
ax.set_ylabel('Y(t)')
ax.set_title('2D Discretized Brownian Paths')

## Create a list of line2D objects
lines = [ax.plot(dat[0, 0:1], dat[1, 0:1])[0] for dat in data]


## Create the animation object
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updateLines, N+1, fargs=(data, lines), interval=30, repeat=True, blit=False)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

## Uncomment to save the animation
#anim.save('brownian2d_1path.mp4', writer=writer)
```

However, instead of performing the plot the program is printing,
[image]

How do I animate this plot? I am new to python so I apologize in advanced if this is an easy question.

I found this question on http://people.bu.edu/andasari/courses/stochasticmodeling/lecture5/stochasticlecture5.html , there is a walkthrough of how this code came to being.

Comment: On my system (pycharm under Windows) it works after removing `matplotlib.use("Agg")` and `writer = Writer(...`. And adding `import numpy as np`.

Comment: Thanks at JohanC, I did the same and seems to work, my problem now is it is saving well as a GIF but not showing as a GIF in the notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JohanC 's help got it to work.

```
#!apt install ffmpeg
#!brew install imagemagick

import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib import animation, rc
from IPython.display import HTML, Image # For GIF

rc('animation', html='html5')
np.random.seed(5)


# Set up formatting for the movie files
Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=15, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)


def generateRandomLines(dt, N):
    dX = np.sqrt(dt) * np.random.randn(1, N)
    X = np.cumsum(dX, axis=1)

    dY = np.sqrt(dt) * np.random.randn(1, N)
    Y = np.cumsum(dY, axis=1)

    lineData = np.vstack((X, Y))

    return lineData


# Returns Line2D objects
def updateLines(num, dataLines, lines):
    for u, v in zip(lines, dataLines):
        u.set_data(v[0:2, :num])

    return lines

N = 501 # Number of points
T = 1.0
dt = T/(N-1)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data = [generateRandomLines(dt, N)]

ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-2.0, 2.0), ylim=(-2.0, 2.0))

ax.set_xlabel('X(t)')
ax.set_ylabel('Y(t)')
ax.set_title('2D Discretized Brownian Paths')

## Create a list of line2D objects
lines = [ax.plot(dat[0, 0:1], dat[1, 0:1])[0] for dat in data]


## Create the animation object
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updateLines, N+1, fargs=(data, lines), 
interval=30, repeat=True, blit=False)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

# Save as GIF
anim.save('animationBrownianMotion2d.gif', writer='pillow', fps=60)

Image(url='animationBrownianMotion2d.gif')
## Uncomment to save the animation
#anim.save('brownian2d_1path.mp4', writer=writer)
```

[image]